# Как инвертировать элемент по горизонтали?

Tags: css, css3

Есть элемент контейнера и в нем обычный span с текстом. Надо инвертнуть его горизонтально, но чтобы текст остался в читабельном виде и при увеличении элемента (больше текста) он бы увеличивался влево, а не вправо по умолчанию.

Что-то вроде этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, тогда вероятность быстрого ответа на ваш вопрос, будет куда больше, чем сейчас.

Comment: Как вариант, предлагаю [изучить](http://htmlbook.ru/css/float).

Comment: Расширьте пожалуйста свой ответ, на данный момент он является не полным. Просто ссылка на сторонний ресурс абсолютно ничего не дает новому пользователю. Если вы предлагаете изучить то что по ссылке, объясните пожалуйста почему так.

Comment: float в моем случае не помогает, если бы было все так просто, тут скорее всего надо как-то через transform: scaleX сделать, но у меня не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стили для контейнера

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

решат вашу проблему.

http://jsfiddle.net/0nwekym3/9/